# link_to_if Why does it show the Link Title if false?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Why does link_to_if show the link title if the condition is false?

I'm using it on a DELETE, and if the condition is false, Rails shows delete but it isn't linked. I don't want DELETE to show up if it's false.

Is there a setting or another helper for that?

Thank you

Answer (score 9):

If you just want the link to disappear completely, just use an 'if' around the link_to, rather than link_to_if.

```
<% if condition %>
  <%= link_to ... %>
<% end %>
```

If you want something *else* to appear when the condition is not true, you can pass a block to render instead. Having said that, from a stylistic perspective, I think I prefer 'if' 'else' to the block syntax - it's less confusing, at least to my eye.

Block syntax:

```
<%= link_to_if(condition, "Link Title", dest ) { link_to( "Alt Title", alt_dest ) } %>
```

If/else syntax:

```
<% if condition %>
  <%= link_to "Link Title", dest %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to "Alt Title", alt_dest %>
<% end >
```

For more information see the documentation for [UrlHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to_if).

Answer (score 8):

You can take advantage of the block and just use instead of the if/else structure:

```
<%= link_to_if(message.user, 'Poster', message.user){} %>
```

In this case, since the block is empty, it won't show anything if the condition is *false*.

Answer (score 1):

For more information -

The complete syntax of `link_to_if` is-

```
link_to_if(condition, name, options = {}, html_options = {}, &block)
```

If you go through the source, you'll find that if the condition is false, it'll try to execute the given block & when a block is not given it'll just return the `name`.

The trick to avoid displaying name is to just specify an empty block as explained by @JoaoDaniel-

```
<%= link_to_if(message.user, 'Poster', message.user, class: 'htmlClass') {} %>
```